# Query on twitterfall.com for accessing live Twitter feeds?

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, real-time

The site twitterfall.com provides all live [Twitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter) feeds by almost everyone with some delay.
How can I access or get live [tweets](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tweet#Noun) (of everybody) from this site or any other option, that you suggest to my C# .NET application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using LinqToTwitter;
using LinqToTwitter.Common;

namespace TwitterConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Here We go .. ");

            var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext();

            var publicTweets =
                from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
                where tweet.Type == StatusType.Public
                select tweet;

            publicTweets.ToList().ForEach(
                tweet => Console.WriteLine(
                    "User Name: {0}, Tweet: {1}",
                    tweet.User.Name,
                    tweet.Text));

            Console.WriteLine("Press2Exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Have a Look [here](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/documentation) !!

Answer (score 3):

LINQ to Twitter is a solid API. http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/.  If you scroll to the end of the main page they have a list of sites that use it.

Comment: I've used some Twitter API libraries before and LINQ to Twitter worked like a charm ;)

Comment: [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) API or solid API?

Answer (score 1):

For .NET I suggest [twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/),

> "the .NET library designed for quick and easy Twitter integration" - twitterizer.net

You could also take a look at the [Twitter API](http://dev.twitter.com/doc) and create your own Twitter library.

Answer (score 1):

You should write your code against the Twitter API instead. You can get access to the firehose if you beg, but most likely, what you need is available in the Stream API Look at the stream api: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_methods

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Twitterfall has an API beyond the one you can use for searching replies. If you're looking to index a large volume of tweets I'd recommend using a service like Collecta instead: http://developer.collecta.com/

Comment: Thats site seems intresting!!But can you guide on how to get live real-time twitter feeds

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the popular framework like [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/) or use the [Twitter API](http://dev.twitter.com/doc) to interact with Twitter. But in order to fetch the tweets, you would have to develop your own logic.

Basically,

- You would need to poll Twitter to
  check for the available status
  updates for the users you have at
  regular intervals.
- You can have multiple threads to keep
  a track of different users.
- You would also have to be cautious about hitting the per hour request limit for the Twitter API